# Log4perl - was working - now zero length files

Tags: perl, cron

Situation: cron job that has been running at 1am for about 5 years. Creates a main log and hundreds of sub-logs (pulling data from remote locations).

Starting on 12/31: instead of the usual 200Kb files they are now 0Kb. The job is still working as it should but no log data is generated. All the sub-logs are created but are also 0Kb.

**If the job is run via interactive shell it works fine.**

What I've looked at:

- no errors in cron log
- no errors in system log
- have compared 'env' output from cron and interactive shell - no diff
- no updates to YUM or CPAN
- file system has more than adequate space

I've reduced my tests down to about 10 lines of code - start, setup logs, write to logs and to stdout and exit. Stdout gives me what I expect in either case (pipe stdout and stderr to file). Log files only have content when run via interactive shell.

What have I missed?

System is running RHEL 5.x server (x64)

EDIT: This is how the logfile appenders are setup:

```
sub initLogging
{
  my $self = shift;
  my $logFileInfo = shift;
  my $dataDir = $self->{ 'localDir' };

  my $logger = get_logger( "Home" . $self->{ 'homeId' } );
  my $appender = Log::Log4perl::Appender->new(
    "Log::Log4perl::Appender::File",
    filename => "${dataDir}/log/$logFileInfo.log" );

  my $layout = Log::Log4perl::Layout::PatternLayout->new( "[%d{yyyy.MMM.dd HH:mm:ss Z}] %p %c - %m%n" );

  $appender->layout( $layout );
  $appender->threshold( $INFO );
  $logger->add_appender( $appender );

  my $appender0 = Log::Log4perl::Appender->new( "Log::Log4perl::Appender::Screen",
                              name => 'screenlog',
                              stderr => 0);

  $appender0->layout( $layout );
  $appender0->threshold( $FATAL );
  $logger->add_appender( $appender0 );
  $self->{ 'logger' } = $logger;
}
```

Calling program:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use pull_common;
use DBI;
use strict;

print "start\n";

# build the main log file name
my @dt = localtime();
my $logFile = sprintf("justtesting-%04d%02d%02d-%02d%02d%02d", $dt[5] + 1900, $dt[4] + 1, $dt[3], $dt[2], $dt[1], $dt[0] );

my $common = new pull_common( );
$common->{ 'homeId' } = 0;
$common->initLogging( $logFile );
my $logger = $common->{ 'logger' };

$logger->info( "this is a test. This is only a test. Remain calm." );
print "end\n";
```

Comment: It might help if you show the code that generates the logs.

Comment: Sorry, should have been more clear...can you show ~10 lines of code you used for testing? That would be more helpful, since I assume it's a complete program that reproduces the issue, not just an isolated subroutine that nobody except you could run.

Comment: All my test code does it call this function to setup the log files and then use the '->error("some output here" )' function. It works via shell but not cron.

Comment: I assume it also does things like set `localDir` and `homeId`, and hopefully also `use strict; use warnings;`, but I don't know, I'm just guessing. If you don't post a complete, working program, the best anyone can do is guess at your problem. Not that we'll necessarily be able to reproduce the issue even if you do provide all the code, but it will at least eliminate some possibilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FWIW: It seems that I had been playing 'fast and loose' with `Log4perl` for many years. Something got updated and the requirement for initializing the library started getting enforced.

Short answer: add a call to `Log::Log4perl->easy_init( $DEBUG );` before you call `get_logger()`. Then add your appenders (at whatever level you want) and you should be good to go.